# how to get the value of inner div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the inner div and get it's value using Javascript.
Would you please help me, I want to get the value of "phone" and insert it into a "list". I don't how to loop in all the DIVS and get only the checked one's below my setup:

```
<div class="headings_01">
<div class="checkbox_01"><input name="contact_id" id="selectedcontacts" type="checkbox" value="175" style="margin-top:0px;" /></div>
<div class="firstname_01" name="fname">|175|James</div>
<div class="lastname_01" name="lname">James</div>
<div class="group_01">G1</div>
<div class="mobile_nmbr_01" name="phone" id="phone">123456478</div>
</div>
```

I have tried this and did not success:

```
function AddContactPhoneNo()
{   
    var recipientNumber = document.getElementById("phone");
    var opt = "<option value='" + recipientNumber.value + "'>" + recipientNumber.value + "</option>"

    if  (recipientNumber.value != "")
    {
         $('#selectedOptions').append(opt);

            recipientNumber.value = "";

    }       
}
```

Comment: Try: recipientNumber.innerHTML

Comment: If you're using [tag:javascript] please add that to the tags (and remove 'div' and 'child,' since people are unlikely to be browsing for questions about those tags). Also, if you're using jQuery, add that tag as well.

Comment: @AlejandroMartin or instead of using [innerHTML magic/garbage](https://gist.github.com/1404876) you could try `recipientNumber.innerText || recipientNumber.textContent`. or `recipientNumber.childNodes[0]` all would be better solutions. also you answer offers no explanation, just a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i'm late responser about the udate of my answer but i'm sure if you find even now the solution then it will help you much. You should change your HTML first then write the jQuery code as like following block of code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="headings_01">
   <div class="checkbox_01">
     <input name="contact_id[]" type="checkbox" value="175" style="margin-top:0px;" />
   </div>
   <div class="firstname_01" name="fname">|175|James</div>
   <div class="lastname_01" name="lname">James</div>
   <div class="group_01">G1</div>
   <div class="mobile_nmbr_01">+8801711240984</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function AddContactPhoneNo()
{ 
    $("input[name='contact_id[]']:checked").each(function(){

        var opt_value = $(this).parent().parent().children('.mobile_nmbr_01').text();
        var opt = "<option value='" + opt_value + "'>" + opt_value + "</option>";

        if  (opt_value != "")
        {
             $('#selectedOptions').append(opt);
        }
    });
}
```

Thats all. Very simple.

Comment: I used **recipientNumber.html()** it cut the **phone** and past it in the list :) , but my requirements is to loop in all the checkboxes if it is checked so copy the phone of that particular div.

Comment: Ok then use `.each()` and use checkbox name like `checkboxname[]`

Comment: Thanks Arif for your kind reply. Can you write the syntax for me how to make the loop :)

Comment: is this correct:????'$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
           if (this.checked) {function AddContactPhoneNo()
{   
    var recipientNumber = $("#phone").text();
    var opt = "<option value='" + recipientNumber + "'>" + recipientNumber + "</option>";

    if  (recipientNumber != "")
    {
         $('#selectedOptions').append(opt);
    }       
}
               
}'

Comment: Please see my update answer. It's totally for you. Done your whole job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of such repeating phone divs

set a counter value

```
var counter = 0;
var phoneDiv = "phone" + counter;

var a = document.getElementById(phoneDiv).innerHTML

counter++;
```

Comment: Would you please help me how to write this code but with loop to loop in all checkboxes and see which is checked and get the phone value

Comment: When I call the function I only get the value of "phone" of the first Div, even if it is not checked. I want the value of "phone" when the div checkbox is checked, how that can be ?

Comment: So, do you have a number of such repeating phones ? How can you name each of them with same id "phone" then ? I will edit my answer to add that code for you

Comment: Now in your html , you need to name your divs of phone as phone0, phone1, phone2 etc. It will work :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the logic that I want is to get the "phone" if the checkbox is checked ?

Comment: I didnt get u . Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: I have a list of contacts [checkbox-firstname-lastname-Group-Phone] I want to get the phone of the checked records when I press of "add contact" example: [[checkbox] James   Lonli     G1    99999], another record [[checkbox] Tania   Lonli     G2    11111], So if I check the first record and press add contact, I should get only the phone of that checked row.